# Is there any way to export the html page's data into PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have an html page which contains multiple selectboxes, labels, input fields and checkboxes.
I want to export entire html page into PDF. is there any way I can do so? Any `javascript` or `library for exporting HTML into PDF`?

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need to do generate your PDF using Javascript, you can use [JsPDF](http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf) :

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

// Output as Data URI
doc.output('datauri');
```

But you will have to recreate your html page with the library's syntaxe.

If generating your document don't necessary have to be done with Javascript, a better way would be to use a php library.

In the past I used (DomPdf)[https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf] : very powerfull. It just take a HTML/CSS document and create a PDF version of it.

If you absolutely need a non-refresh loading, you can use Ajax to generate the document.

Answer (score 1):

Give e try to JsPDF: http://jspdf.com/ :)
Regards!